# Закрытие формы после события

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Уважаемые форумчане, не кидайтесь сразу грязными носками.
Я только начал учить java script  и на первой пробе сломал всю голову как сделать так чтобы когда всплывающее окно появилось, человек нажал на кнопку отправить форма исчезла/закрылась.

Код отправики данных

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    var  
    phone = $(this).closest('form').find('#input_2843, #phone').val(),
    name = $(this).closest('form').find('#input_2599, #name').val(),
    email = $('.col-sm-12').find('#input_2022').val(),
    comment = $('[class="popup active"]').find('.event-header').text();
    var 
    visit = '';
 if(typeof name == 'undefined'){name = '';}
            if(typeof phone == 'undefined'){phone = '';}
            if(typeof name == 'undefined'){name = '';}
            if(typeof email == 'undefined'){email = '';}
            if(typeof comment == 'undefined'){comment = '';}
            if (typeof WBK !== 'undefined') {
                visit = WBK.settings.visitId; 
            }
        data = "name=" + name + 
        "&phone=" + phone + 
        "&email=" + email +
        "&comment=" + comment
        "&url=" + document.location.href;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "https://sayt.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

код всплывающего окна

```
<div id="popup-coust-led" class="popup">
  <div class="popup-content">
    <div class="event-header">
      <h6>Познакомимся?</h6>
    </div>
      <form id="send" class="send-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Имя..." id="name" name="name" required="required">
          <label for="name">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="tel" placeholder="Телефон..." id="phone" name="phone" required="required">
          <label for="phone">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="main-btn-rect" name="text" value="Send">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>Получить консультацию</button>
      </form>
    <span class="fade-out main-btn-circle">╳</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Код для появления окна

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.popup-btn').click(function(){ 
    var popupBlock = $('#'+$(this).data('popup'));
    popupBlock.addClass('active')
      .find('.fade-out').click(function(){
        popupBlock.css('opacity','0').find('.popup-content').css('margin-top','350px');        
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('.popup').removeClass('active');
          popupBlock.css('opacity','').find('.popup-content').css('margin-top','');
        }, 600);
      });
 });
});
```

Как можно сделать чтобы после отправки окно закрылось.

Заранее благодарю тех кто откликнется на зов помощи...

Comment: С удовольствием помогу, если ты очистишь часть лишнего, не особо читабельного кода. Оставь только суть и отформатируй его где нибудь в JSPrettier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заработало при таком коде

```
$('[type="submit"]').click(function(){
   $('.fade-out.main-btn-circle').trigger("click");
   $(this).closest('form')[0].reset();
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[type="submit"]').click(function(evt){
  ...

  evt.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest(".popup").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: К сожалению код не работает.